# How to use javascript and Php to clear a cart of its values?

Tags: javascript, php, cart

I've created a shopping cart which works well.

Im having a problem clearing the cart, i want to use javascript to do this.

I want to use a button so when pressed it asks the user to confirm if they want to clear it, and if ok is pressed it is cleared.

So i have created the php code to clear my cart:

```
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
```

And when this is assigned to a link it clears the cart. 
For example:

```
<a href="cart.php?cmd=emptycart">Empty Cart</a>
```

However i want to change this to a button.

So far i have the following javascript code to give the validation but does not clear the cart.

```
<script language="javascript">

    function clear_cart(){
        if(confirm('Shopping cart will be cleared. Continue?')){
            document.form1.command.value='emptycart';
            document.form1.submit();
        }
}
</script>
```

The button:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()">
```

So my question is how do i get this to clear using this button and with the use of javascript or AJAX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done with jQuery and AJAX.

```
function clear_cart( ) {
    if( confirm( 'Shopping cart will be cleared. Continue?' ) ) {
        $.get( "cart.php?cmd=emptycart", function( data ) {
            alert( "Cart has been cleared!" );
        });
    }
}
```

More information on .get() is here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

If you prefer to not use jQuery, this might help: http://blog.mgechev.com/2011/07/21/ajax-jquery-beginners/

Comment: Doesnt work, when Okay is pressed on the popup, nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah, managed to load it and it works, but i need to manually refresh the page to see the cart cleared. How do i autorefresh this using this code?

Comment: You can download a local copy of jQuery or use a CDN. This link has details: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Yeah, managed to load it and it works, but i need to manually refresh the page to see the cart cleared. How do i autorefresh this using this code?

Comment: You'll need to create or call a refresh function from the same place as the alert() in the .get() call. That function is a success post-back.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept answer. Glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="emptycart" />
    <input type="submit" name="empty_cart_submit" value="Empty Cart" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?');" />
</form>
```

---

For a solution without a page reload:

From your main page you want to call a script to unset the `$_SESSION`, but rather than reload the page you can use ajax to reload only the cart itself.

Say you have a file which is a sub-view just for the contents of the cart, called in your main page like

```
<div id="cart-contents">
    //with a function
    <?php echo get_cart_sub_view(); ?>
    //or with an inlude
    <?php include('cart_sub_view.php'); ?>
</div>
```

You can ajax in your new cart contents using jQuery load.

You need a script to generate the html that goes inside the cart, which you can call via ajax (i.e cart_sub_view.php).

After the `$_SESSION` unset call, call

```
$("#cart-contents").load(
    'cart_sub_view.php'
);
```

Which will ajax to the sub view page, and then copy its contents into the cart-contents div.

Comment: While this accomplishes the goal, his question was specifically to find a way to use AJAX, not html form code. One might argue against using HTML for resetting a shopping cart because it doesn't need to take any inputs from the user and doesn't allow the shopping cart to be reset before the page loads (if that becomes a goal). It also doesn't provide any way to handle an error (if one occurs). I find very limited use for HTML forms now that AJAX is around.

Comment: If you want to do this without a page load then I suggest using the first part of Kivak Wolf's answer to unset the session data and also request new content for the cart at the same time. Seems the simplest way of doing it without databinding.

Comment: I have edited my answer to suggest a solution though I can't go into too much detail without knowing how you're building this site.